# How can I use memcmp to get an account with a certain u32 value?

Tags: anchor, web3.js, getprogramaccounts

I'm trying to fetch all of a certain account that matches defined u32 values.  My account struct looks something like this:

```
#[account]
pub struct Round {
    pub bump: u8, // 1
    pub authority: Pubkey, // 32
    pub state: RoundState, // 1
    pub participants: u16, // 2
    pub id: u32, // 4,
}
```

What I have now is, but it doesn't seem to be fetching anything.  I've tried using different iterations of UInt8Array, but can't quite figure it out.  Is it possible to search like this?

```
const rounds = [
      { dataSize: ROUND_SIZE },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 1 + 32 + 1 + 2,
          bytes: roundId,
        },
      },
    ];
```

Also, is it possible to search for multiple different parameters?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the problem is that you're not accounting for the discriminator, which is 8 bytes prepended to the account and therefore also the offset.

I think you want:

```
const rounds = [
      { dataSize: ROUND_SIZE },
      {
        memcmp: {
          offset: 8 + 1 + 32 + 1 + 2,
          bytes: roundId,
        },
      },
    ];
```

See eg. https://lorisleiva.com/create-a-solana-dapp-from-scratch/fetching-tweets-from-the-program#filtering-tweets-by-topic

Comment: Do you know how I would create a bytes string for a u32 number?  It only seems to work when looking for one if I convert the base10 number to a base58 string

Comment: I think the conversion you mention is what you need to do: "data to match, as base-58 encoded string and limited to less than 129 bytes" from https://coral-xyz.github.io/anchor/ts/modules/web3.html#MemcmpFilter

Comment: Yeah I see that in the docs, but I'm unsure how to properly turn the integer into a base58 string.  Nothing I'm doing seems to be returning the right results